# Drupal fb Like Box Css

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

Im making a website using Drupal 7.
I just installed the '**Social Media**' and '**Widgets**' Modules.
Then I added the fb like box to the left sidebar region of my danblog theme.

[image: Heres a screenshot]

As you can see the box overflows the block.
Can I solve it by some configuration or do I need to change the css manually?

I wanted to know where exactly can I find the CSS of these blocks so that I could try to change it?
There are so many .php files and some .css files in drupal.

If someone could please elaborate on some technique or some basic understanding by which I can find the styling of blocks in those php files as I assume they may not be in seperate .css files

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix **not recommended**:

```
#f3c805688 { width: 220px!important; }
```

You really don't want to use `!important` it works as a quick fix in this case, but the ideal fix would be to change the height of the iFrame before inserting it into the page via some backend interface.  Does the social media module have an option to change the width?

Comment: It asks me for a default settings for widget appearance with a width and a height. It had 292 as width and 300 as height by deafult. I removed that. But it still doesnt work :(

Comment: Instead of removing it put in 220 for the width

Comment: Yes. It works now. Why didnt I think of that :P Thanks a ton :)